# Linearization of if-then when having both binary and non-negative

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization

How to linearize the if-then statements when the condition is a binary and the result is equality between two non-negative?

Three variables:

$\gamma_{i}^{t,s} \in \{0,1\}$  and $x_{i}^{t} \in  \mathbb{R}$ and $y_{i}^{t} \in  \mathbb{R}$

The If-Then

- $ \gamma_{i}^t \implies x_{i}^{t} = y_{i}^{t} $
- $ \gamma_{i}^t  \iff x_{i}^{t} = y_{i}^{t} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $L_x \le x \le U_x$ and $L_y \le y \le U_y$.  Then you can enforce the indicator constraint
$$\gamma = 1 \implies x = y$$
via linear big-M constraints
$$(L_x-U_y)(1-\gamma) \le x - y \le (U_x-L_y)(1-\gamma).$$

To enforce the equivalence
$$\gamma = 1 \iff x = y,$$
introduce small constant tolerance $\epsilon > 0$,
binary variables $\alpha$ and $\beta$,
and linear constraints
\begin{align}
\alpha + \gamma + \beta &= 1 \\
(L_x-U_y)\alpha + 0\gamma + \epsilon\beta \le x - y &\le -\epsilon\alpha + 0\gamma + (U_x-L_y)\beta
\end{align}